# nivo-slider function not working in ruby on rails application using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, i want to use image-slider for sliding multiple images like below:

```
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="assets/slide-01.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="assets/slide-02.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="assets/slide-03.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
```

and I am using below jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Cufon.replace('h1, h2', {
    hover: true
});

$(window).load(function ()
 {

     $("#slider").nivoSlider({

       alert("Hassan");
       /*effect: 'sliceDown',

        slices: 20,

        animSpeed: 500,

        pauseTime: 3000,

        startSlide: 0,

        directionNav: false,

        directionNavHide: false,

        controlNav: false,

        controlNavThumbs: false,

        controlNavThumbsFromRel: false,

        keyboardNav: false,

        pauseOnHover: true,

        manualAdvance: false,

        captionOpacity: 0.5,

        beforeChange: function () {},

        afterChange: function () {},

        slideshowEnd: function () {} */
    });

});

</script>
```

Below is the `nivoSlider` class:

```
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:60;
    display:none;
}
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    height:100%;
}
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.8;
    width:100%;
    z-index:89;
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:99;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

But its not going into the `nivoSlider` function. Why?

Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this to debug, your alert is not positionned where it should and breaking the plugin.

```
$("#slider").nivoSlider({
  afterLoad: function(){
    alert('whatever');
    }
  });
```

Comment: You got Turbolinks enabled?

Answer (score 0):

[**Unobtrusive Javascript**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript)

First of all, you need to make sure you put your JS into your `asset_pipeline` Javascripts files. Putting pure JS in your views is [configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), and as such will cause a mess down the line.

You should at least put the code into the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file - thus allowing you to reference it from any view of your application

--

**Turbolinks**

The likely issue you have (although I could be wrong), is that Turbolinks will be preventing your `$(window).load` function from working.

If you're using Turbolinks, you'll be much better suited to using one of the [Turbolinks event hooks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to run the code you need:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var slider = function(){
     $("#slider").nivoSlider({
         ...
     });
}
$(document).on("page:load ready", slider);
```

BY THE WAY - when you have a JS function that accepts arguments, you will NOT be able to call an `alert` from it. From a function, yes, but from an arguments hash, no:

```
$("#slider").nivoSlider({ //NO ALERT HERE });
```

--

**Files**

Further, you need to make sure you have loaded the files correctly.

One of the classic problems you'll have is you've neglected to include the `nivoSlider` files you require in your asset pipeline; preventing it from loading correctly, if at all.

To fix this, you need to make sure you're calling all the necessary files in your asset pipeline; which can typically be done either with the manifest directives in your `application.js` file, or by just including in your layout directly